# Delete function not working Error like this JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Param"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, json

This is angular code.I have like this delete function code. When run it I have like this **error:**

> JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Param"

```
$scope.delete = function(cart_ID, index) {
var params = $.param({"cart_ID":cart_ID});
console.log(cart_ID);
 $http({
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        url: 'http://localhost/test1/shopCartProductDelete.php?cart_ID'+ cart_ID, 
        method: "GET",
        data: params


}).success(function(data){
$scope.data.splice(index, 1);


 });
```

**shopCartProductDelete.phpt**

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8");
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","look4com_lk");
if(isset($_GET['cart_ID'])){
$cart_ID = $_GET['cart_ID'];
$res = "DELETE FROM l4wlk_cart WHERE cart_ID='".$cart_ID."'";
mysqli_query($con, $res) or mysqli_error($con);
}else{
die("Param value not set up"); 
}
```

Comment: You are not sending corrected json formatted data from PHP server.Please check in response

Comment: you need to reffer https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: what is the json formatted data from PHP server, can you give me answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an `=` in your jQuery AJAX request (*might not be relevant, but you're best to check that `$_GET['cart_ID']` is actually being sent to your PHP script via the `data`*):

```
url: 'http://localhost/test1/shopCartProductDelete.php?cart_ID'+ cart_ID
```

Should be:

```
url: 'http://localhost/test1/shopCartProductDelete.php?cart_ID='+ cart_ID
```

---

Now if you're trying to harness it as `json`, you need to send `application/json`, not `text/plain`:

```
echo json_encode(['error' => true, 'message' => 'Param not set']);
```

Comment: where to I need to add `echo`

Answer (score 1):

This means that you're hitting the `else` branch in PHP. So the response is `Param value not set up`, which jQuery attempts to parse as JSON. Because the response is not valid JSON, it is telling you that the first identifier (`Param`) was unexpected.

You need to determine why `isset($_GET['cart_ID'])` is `false` and fix that, and possibly improve the error handling (either return a JSON payload or change the MIME type of the response).

Comment: What I can do for this. I cant understand my friend

Comment: @DRK: Try using a tool like Fiddler to view the request/response being sent between the client and server, or debug your PHP code to check why `cart_ID` has not been set correctly.

Comment: when i put url with cart_ID as link on the browser. It will work

Comment: @DRK: Then add an equal sign after `cart_ID` in your request so it looks like `url: 'http://localhost/test1/shopCartProductDelete.php?cart_ID='+ cart_ID`. Because the equal sign is missing, the parameter isn't being passed correctly.